# Primefaces InputMask doesn't work if created programmatically

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an application that's built on **primefaces 12** to generate dynamic pages based on backend database, and I create InputMask as follows :

```
Application application = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
InputMask inputNumber = (InputMask) application.createComponent(InputMask.COMPONENT_TYPE);
inputNumber.setMask("999999999999999"); 
inputNumber.setSlotChar("");
inputNumber.setAutoClear(false);
inputNumber.setValidateMask(false);
inputNumber.setId(property.getSymbolicName());
inputNumber.setMaxlength(15);
myPanelGrid().getChildren().add(inputNumber);
```

Issue : the mask doesn't work in my xhtml page and I get error in console :

```
Widget class 'InputMask' not found!
```

So I tried manually to import the inputMask script as follows :

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="inputmask/inputmask.js" target="head" />
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="validation/validation.js" target="head" />
```

But it didn't work also
The only working workaround was to manually add in page a hidden inputMask component as follows :

```
<p:inputMask style="display:none"/>
```

Question : How to make the inputMask works fine without this workaround ?

Comment: See https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/9329

Comment: Yep wrote a test case its working just fine